# is there a DE JURE ebook specification

Tags: standards

Is there a *de jure* e-book standard or specification (as distinct from a *de facto* standard)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, and because it makes me want to die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that depends on who's law you're looking at. The International Digital Publishing Forum ( http://idpf.org/ ) has chosen epub as its standard, however.

Comment: Thanks -- that's what I meant -- a non-proprietary specification rather than a proprietary format that is regarded as the de facto standard because of its widespread use.